# WebSocket connection timed out in EC2 website

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-ec2, websocket

I have a problem that seems to me to be impossible to solve, well, I have a website on EC2, I bought my own domain, I added HTTPS using Let's encrypt, and on this website there is a chat, and I am using the PHP Ratchet library to create a connection with websockets, and the problem is that my server doesn't start in the browser, well, I've tried to make my server start with several ports, 3000, 8080, 8181, 8443, 4433, and none of these work, at least when I use the command php chat-server.php to start the PHP server, I don't get any errors, it works, however, when entering the browser, it doesn't display a message in the PHP script console saying that there is a new connection, and the browser console ( chrome) reports a timed out error, that is, it looks like you are not connecting to the server, I really don't know what to do anymore, I don't know if this is because of the HTTPS I'm using, I don't know if should I edit something in the apache configuration, I need the someone help me, please
In fact, I already edited the security group in EC2, I already enabled these ports that I said I tried to use, I restarted the Apache server too and I still get the same error

**PHP CODE - chat-server.php :**

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Local\Socket\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
         ),
        4433
    );

    $server->run();
```

**JS CODE:**

```
var conn = new WebSocket("wss://example.net:4433/chat.php");
```

**ERROR:**

> failed: Error in connection establishment:
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OU

Comment: This could be a lot of different things. The very first thing I would check is the apache access logs- is apache seeing a connection or not? If it is then you need to debug between apache and php, and if it's not you need to debug between the user and apache. Once you've figure that out you can start narrowing the issue down further.

Comment: I'm going crazy, I don't know what to do, now when I try to use port 8443, it says the port is already in use, and when I try to stop its execution, it doesn't stop, tell me, this port I'm using is the right one ? Are there others I can use? I no longer know what to do to solve this, I've seen several topics but none with a definitive answer

Comment: PHP script reports now: Address already in use(port in use) and the Browser says: failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out, it looks like a problem in the server, there's other port that I should use? Appropriate to HTTPS

Comment: I'd take a breath, step back, and maybe consider starting fresh. I've been in situations repeatedly where my debugging has gotten the system into a weird state and that may be happening here. Launch a fresh machine, install apache, and confirm you can load a static web page through it. Then get SSL working and load a page to confirm. Then start adding the PHP service with your script.